# Apache-FOP - Xsl template input variable

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I wanted solution for using input parameter in xsl template? and input parameter value should be passed from java class. Is there any solution available please post your response ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Applying xslt transformations has nothing to do with FOP; it's a job for an XSLT processor (Xalan, Saxon, ...). So, how to pass stylesheet parameters with java code depends on the XSLT processor, not FOP.

For the users' convenience, Xalan is included with FOP, and FOP can accept xml + xslt input.

FOP's website has a detailed page about [java embedding](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/embedding.html#examples), and  [this example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/examples/embedding/java/embedding/ExampleXML2PDF.java?view=markup) should cover your use case (these examples are also included in FOP's distributions, in the `examples/java/embedding/` folder).

This little fragment, quoted from the linked example, shows how to set parameters:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

...

File xsltfile = new File(baseDir, "path/to/you/stylesheet.xsl");

// Setup XSLT
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

// Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
transformer.setParameter("yourParameterName", "yourVvalue");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you currently call FOP - via a command line command? If so, there is a `param` parameter for passing values to XSLT stylesheet parameters. See [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/running.html).